# Using sample() when x is of varying length

Tags: r

I have a list where different rows are of different length (sometimes length of 1)

I would like to apply sample to each row by using

`sapply(1:99,function(x) sample(mat[[]],1))`

The problem of course is that whenever the row is of length one sample will choose from 1:x instead of always choose the same number.

Is there a way to force sample to return the same value whenever length is of 1? 
What is an alternative way to avoid this problem?

Comment: "I have a matrix with where different rows are of different length" - I think you're going to have to explain that more fully. A matrix can't have different "length" rows.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but `sapply` should be formatted as: `sapply(mat[1:99], sample, size=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `1:x` thing is hard coded into `sample`, the best option is just to use `ifelse`:

```
sapply(mat[1:99], function(x) if(length(x)==1) x else sample(x, 1))
```

Comment: Error in mat[[1:99]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2

Comment: the problem is that I have a list which needs to be indexed with [[]]

Comment: No, if you're using `sapply` then you don't use `[[]]`, `sapply` does that for you.

Comment: It seems strange to use the vectorized `ifelse` function inside the `sapply` where it will not be given a vector with more than 1 element.  Regular `if ... else ...` might be more efficient.

Comment: @GregSnow You're probably right - I think I just have a habit of using `ifelse` if there's only one line of code for each condition.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the example on the help page `?sample`:

```
resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]
```

Just use the above `resample` function in place of `sample`.  Or rename it, modify it, etc. if you want it to work a little differently.

To satisfy my own curiosity I did a quick benchmark of the suggestions so far:

```
library(microbenchmark)

mylist <- lapply( sample( rep( 1:10, 10 ) ), rpois, lambda=3 )

resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]
sample1 <- function(x) x[sample.int(length(x), 1)]
ie1 <- function(x) if(length(x)==1) x else sample(x,1)
ie2 <- function(x) ifelse( length(x)==1, x, sample(x,1) )
rep1 <- function(x) { if( length(x) < 2 ) x <- rep(x,2); sample(x,1) }

(out <- microbenchmark( 
    sapply(mylist, resample, size=1),
    sapply(mylist, sample1),
    sapply(mylist, ie1),
    sapply(mylist, ie2),
    sapply(mylist, rep1)
))
```

With results:

```
Unit: microseconds
                               expr      min        lq    median        uq      max neval
 sapply(mylist, resample, size = 1)  360.846  388.1455  398.4085  409.4925 2036.169   100
            sapply(mylist, sample1)  339.499  365.7720  375.8300  391.6345 1846.100   100
                sapply(mylist, ie1)  493.853  534.2900  543.3205  561.3840 2091.589   100
                sapply(mylist, ie2) 1225.397 1291.6955 1328.4365 1395.1455 3787.850   100
               sapply(mylist, rep1)  566.926  614.3405  627.2720  649.4405 2178.209   100
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have `matrix` vs.  `dataframe` or whatever it is straightened out, here's a workaround I've used:

```
vec.len<-length(my_vector)
if (vec.len <2 ) my_vector<-rep(my_vector,2)
sample(my_vector,1)
```